# New thread from Callable instead of Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

Threads are normally created from `Runnable`s. Is there a way to create a thread from a `Callable`?

```
public class AddNumImmediately implements Callable {
    private int minRange;
    private int maxRange;
    private Set<Integer> primeNumberList;
    private int step;

    public AddNumImmediately(int minRange, int maxRange, Set<Integer> primeNumberList, int step) {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.primeNumberList = primeNumberList;
        this.step = step;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() {
        for (int i = minRange; i <= maxRange; i += step) {
            if (PrimeChecker.isPrimeNumber(i)) {
                primeNumberList.add(i);
            }
        }
        return primeNumberList;
    }
}
```

And then I try to run my Callable via Thread:

```
public void setup(int min, int max, int threadNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    Set<Integer> primeNumberList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
        threadList.add(new Thread(String.valueOf(new AddNumImmediately(min, max, primeNumberList, threadNumber))));
    }
    for (Thread thread : threadList) {
        thread.start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : threadList) {
        thread.join();
    }
    System.out.println(primeNumberList);
}
```

I know that `Callable`s can be run by an `Executor`, but is it possible to somehow run them through `Thread`?

Comment: your call() method returns primeNumberList. But this value is already known to the caller thread, so you can omit `return primeNumberList;` and convert Callable to Runnable.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Callable` wrong. A callable returns a `<V>`, which will become a `Future<V>` when submitted via an `ExecutorService`, if you don't work with them, you pick `Runnable`.

**Callable**:

> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception. Implementors
>   define a single method with no arguments called call.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

**Runnable**

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose
>   instances are intended to be executed by a thread. The class must
>   define a method of no arguments called run.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

So the proper way with callables would be to return a `Set<Integer>` and merge these Futures together in your `primeNumberList`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create a thread from a Callable?

Short answer:  No.  The `Thread` API requires a `Runnable` not a `Callable`.

You can work around this with a `Runnable` wrapper for a `Callable`, though getting the result from the `Callable` is a bit messy!  A much better idea is to use an `ExecutorService`.  That allows you to avoid the problems of not creating too many threads and (alternatively) managing your own thread pool.

It is work noting that your example doesn't really need a `Callable`.  You are returning a `Set` that was provided in the `AddNumImmediately` constructor.  The caller could simply keep a reference to that `Set` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Callable` with a `Runnable`. Use this helper function to create `Thread` from `Callable`.

```
public static Thread createThreadFromCallable(@NonNull Callable<?> callable) {
    return new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What use has the callable with this construct? None, you can skip it completely since you don't work with the future anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new thread from callable. That's there. For a new thread, Thread has to come into picture.
Being said that you can use FurtureTask with callable and Thread to get your result back. You can try something like this:

```
FutureTask<String> f1 = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return "A constant from " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
});

Thread t = new Thread(f1);
t.start();
System.out.println("Calling Get " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
System.out.println(f1.get());
System.out.println("Got Get");
```

will give you output as :

Calling Get main

A constant from Thread-0

Got Get